# Unit test-Give a fake value to the variables initialized by constructor

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I have a class

Test.ts:

```
class Test
{
     public property1: string;
     public property2: boolean;
     constructor(property1, property2)
     {
            this.property1 = property1;//will get value while instantiation
            this.property2 = property2;//will get value while instantiation
            this.property3 = somevalue;//want to add fake value here 
     }
}
```

As given above I want to give a fake value for `property3` but `property1` and and `property2` I will get it from instantiation. How can I achieve This?

Comment: TIP: Use the "StackSnippet" utility and click the `<>` button to format your code.

Comment: Please can you edit your question? Otherwise in its current state it's likely to be closed.

Comment: where did that come from? I gave a tip, and asked for you to format your code, that was all.

Comment: _"please concentrate on the main objective"_ I think you need to re-read [ask]

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are struggling with declaring the `property3` member. Simply do it like you declared the other properties. Additional you can use property initializer if you wanted:

```
class Test
{
     public property1: string;
     public property2: boolean;
     public property3 = somevalue;
     constructor(property1, property2)
     {
            this.property1 = property1;//will get value while instantiation
            this.property2 = property2;//will get value while instantiation
     }
}
```

## More

Some docs on TypeScript classes https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/classes.html

Comment: Thanks for reply. I cant move the property up because i want to initialize it at the instantiation time only.So i have to give a fake value there